# A version of Fourier inversion formula for finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory

(Fourier Inversion). Let $G$ be a finite group and $\hat{G}$ a complete set of inequivalent irreducible unitary representations of $G$.   For any $f\in L^2(G)$, we have $$f(x)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\substack{\pi\in \hat{G}\\ 1\leq i,j\leq d_{\pi}}}d_{\pi}\langle f,\pi_{i,j} \rangle\pi_{i,j}(x)$$

Here $d_{\pi}$ denotes the dimension of the representation $
\pi$, and $\pi_{i,j}(x)$ denotes the (i,j) matrix entry of $\pi(x)$.

I try to show that this is equivalent to the following:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in \hat{G}}d_{\pi}\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\pi(x^{-1})\sum_{y\in G}f(y)\pi(y)\Big)$$

Attempt: For any $\pi\in 
\hat{G}$ and $x\in G$, it is enough to show that  $$\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\pi(x^{-1})\sum_{y\in G}f(y)\pi(y)\Big)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq d_{\pi}} \langle f,\pi_{i,j} \rangle\pi_{i,j}(x)$$

But I have 
$$\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\pi(x^{-1})\sum_{y\in G}f(y)\pi(y)\Big)=\sum_{y\in G} f(y) \operatorname{Tr}\big(\pi(x^{-1}y)\big)=\sum_{y\in G}\sum_{i=1}^{d_\pi}f(y)\pi_{i,i}(x^{-1}y)$$

Can any one give a hint from here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some version of the Peter-Weyl theorem / Artin-Wedderburn decomposition to work with? (That's why the dimensions $d_\pi$ appear in the summands after all.)

Comment: I have the Peter-Weyl theorem as follows: All matrix coefficients of the representations in $\hat{G}$ form a orthogonal basis for $L^2(G)$. Thanks for the explanation of $d_{\pi}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we expand $\langle f, \pi_{i,j}\rangle$, we get

$$\sum_{y \in G} f(y) \cdot \overline{\pi_{i,j}(y)},$$

and hence

\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant d_{\pi}} \langle f,\pi_{i,j}\rangle \pi_{i,j}(x)
&= \sum_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant d_{\pi}} \sum_{y\in G} f(y) \overline{\pi_{i,j}(y)}\pi_{i,j}(x) \\
&= \sum_{y\in G} f(y) \sum_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant d_\pi} \pi_{j,i}(y^{-1})\pi_{i,j}(x) \\
&= \sum_{y\in G} f(y) \operatorname{Tr} \bigl(\pi(y^{-1})\pi(x)\bigr) \\
&= \sum_{y \in G} f(y) \operatorname{Tr} \pi(y^{-1}x),
\end{align}

which is very similar to what you want, but not quite the same. And indeed we generally don't have

$$\operatorname{Tr} \pi (x^{-1}y) = \operatorname{Tr} \pi (y^{-1}x).$$

But, we are summing over all (equivalence classes of) irreducible representations. So, if for every irreducible representation $\pi$ you can find an irreducible representation $\psi$ such that for all $x,y\in G$ you have

$$\operatorname{Tr} \pi(x^{-1}y) = \operatorname{Tr} \psi(y^{-1}x),$$

that solves it. Now $x^{-1}y = (y^{-1}x)^{-1}$, and so $\pi(x^{-1}y) = \pi(y^{-1}x)^{-1} = \overline{\pi(y^{-1}x)}^T$ since $\pi$ is unitary, whence

$$\operatorname{Tr} \pi(x^{-1}y) = \overline{\operatorname{Tr} \pi(y^{-1}x)},$$

and thus the conjugate representation to $\pi$, $\psi = \overline{\pi} \colon x \mapsto \overline{\pi(x)}$ does what we want.

Comment: Could you explain the equality $\sum_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant d_\pi} \pi_{j,i}(y^{-1})\pi_{i,j}(x) = \operatorname{Tr} \bigl(\pi(y^{-1})\pi(x)\bigr)$? Thanks.

Comment: Let's write $A = \pi(y^{-1})$ and $B = \pi(x)$, and call the dimension just $d$. Then, starting on the left, we have $$\sum_{1 \leqslant i,j\leqslant d} a_{j,i}b_{i,j} = \sum_{j = 1}^d \Biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^d a_{j,i}b_{i,j}\Biggr) = \sum_{j = 1}^d (AB)_{j,j} = \operatorname{Tr} (AB).$$

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find such a $\psi$.

Comment: Try $\overline{\pi}$, i.e. $\psi(x) = \overline{\pi(x)}$.

Comment: If I am right you define $\psi=\pi\circ inv$ where $inv$ is inversion $x\mapsto x^{-1}$. So we get a map from $\hat{G}\to\hat{G}$. Now we need to show that this is a bijection. Right?

Comment: View it as $\operatorname{conj} \circ \pi$, where $\operatorname{conj}$ is the conjugation of complex matrices. If we invert $x$, we get the factors in the wrong order since $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$. To get the right order of factors, we'd then have to transpose the matrices. But $\pi(x^{-1})^T = (\pi(x)^{-1})^T = \overline{\pi(x)}$ since $\pi$ is a unitary representation. And it's easy to see that $\overline{A\cdot B} = \overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}$ for complex matrices, so $\overline{\pi}$ is a representation iff $\pi$ is one, and one is irreducible iff the other is.